# Como resolver problema de dependencias circulares?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Tengo un problema con algo llamado dependencias circulares, que investigando un poco se debe a que un componente esta requiriendo algo de otro y a su vez este mismo requiere algo del otro.

Por lo cual se crea un conflicto, así que me puse a mirar mi código en detalle para poder encontrar las dependencias circulares y podría decir que en su mayoría es culpa del componente **ChatPage.ts**, pues este esta presente en 4 o 5 servicios que he creado, con el fin de dividir el codigo en partes y que este correctamente organizado.

Para mostrar de mejor forma el problema que estoy teniendo es que en mi codigo estos servicios necesitan interactuar directamente con el `HTML` del componente principal (`ChatPage`).

Asi que pense en crear una referencia estatica de cada uno de los componentes `HTML` que necesitara usar en otro servicio, sin embargo justo esto me genera un problema que me da un dolor de cabeza, y es que si yo hago de estos elementos una referencia estatica luego tendre que importar el componente en los servicios para poder usar su referencia estatica.

A su vez los servicios se usan en el componente padre, por tanto se generan inevitablemente dependencias circulares, y dado a que por el momento no he encontrado una forma de realizar importaciones estaticas en typescript no he encontrado como resolver mi problema.

dejo por aqui el codigo minimo:

**ChatPage.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ChatInfoModalPage } from '../chat-info-modal/chat-info-modal.page';
import SocketManager from './scripts/SocketManager';
import { FileManagerService as FileManager } from './scripts/file-manager.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.page.scss'],
})
export class ChatPage implements OnInit {

  //Static elements
  @ViewChild("sendBtn"                 ) public static sendBtn:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("overlay"                 ) public static overlay:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("fileData"                ) public static fileData:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("buttonsFieldContainer"   ) public static btnFields:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("writtingMsg"             ) public static loadingEl:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("closeOverlay"            ) public static closeOverlay:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("messageField"            ) public static messageInput:ElementRef;
  ...

  public  FM:FileManager;

  constructor(
    public modalCtrl:ModalController, 
    public storage:Storage, 
    public socket: SocketManager   //Dependencias circulares
  ) {
    this.FM = new FileManager(this.socket.socket);    //Dependencias circulares
    this.setup();
  }

}
```

**SocketManager.ts**:

```
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { SocketEventsService as SocketEvents } from '../../../providers/socket-events.service';
import { ChatPage } from '../chat.page';     //Como vemos aqui hay una dependencia circular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export default class SocketManager{
   public socket:Socket;
   public io: any;

   constructor(public socketEvents: SocketEvents){
        this.socket = this.socketEvents.socket;
        this.io = this.socket.ioSocket;
        this.addSocketListeners();
   }

   addSocketListeners(){
         //Frontend socket utilities for receiving data from the backend
        this.socket.on("receiveMsg", data =>{
            this.socketEvents.sendOrReceiveNewMessage(data);
        });

        this.socket.on("receiveFiles", data =>{
            this.socketEvents.receiveFiles(data);
        });

        this.socket.on("startedWriting", ()=>{
            //Como acceder a ChatPage.loadingEl sin crear dependencia circular?
            ChatPage.loadingEl.nativeElement.classList.replace("no-writting", "writting");
        });

        this.socket.on("stoppedWriting", ()=>{
            //Como acceder a ChatPage.loadingEl sin crear dependencia circular?
            ChatPage.loadingEl.nativeElement.classList.replace("writting", "no-writting");
        });
    }

}
```

Esto mismo se repite en otros 2 o 3 archivos, donde los servicios necesitan acceder a ciertos componentes `HTML` del componente principal.

Como podria arreglar estas dependencias circulares que tengo en los archivos?, realmente no he encontrado solucion por mas que pienso, la verdad es que son muchos componentes `HTML` estaticos los que tengo referenciados para poder que otros archivos puedan accederlos, por lo tanto necesitaria una solucion que no sea muy drastica, algo mas bien generico para poder conseguir resolver estas dependencias tambien en los otros archivos.

Comment: Con respecto a los usos de dependencias circulares en el archivo FileManager el cual no he puesto el codigo la verdad es que se usa muchisimo la referencia estatica a muchos elementos `HTML` en ese archivo, pero como se trata de basicamente el mismo problema que se presenta en la clase `SocketManager` no he puesto el codigo de `FileManager`, pues resolviendo el problema de `SocketManager` podria resolver el de los otros servicios.

Comment: Si se requiere de una mayor informacion o algun detalle relevante que no he puesto con gusto lo agregare.

Comment: Posiblemente puedas hacer un servicio que controle `chatPage`. Cargas todas las referencias en el `onInit` y sólo inyectas el servicio. De igual manera lo que necesites en `SocketManager` dentro de `chantPage` puedes agregarlo a este servicio. Solo no agregues el componente completo.

Comment: El problema es que el HTML es el que se tiene que manipular en los servicios y no en el componente principal, pues las partes del chat estan divididos en modulos en base a divide y venceras, ya que son muchas cosas como para poner en un solo componente, seria un lio tener todo junto, con respecto a inyectarlos en `ChatPage`, probe a hacer eso, pero el problema seguiria existiendo, debido a que los servicios requieren de ciertos componentes HTML en `ChatPage.ts`

Comment: Es posible que repliques el problema en [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)?